# Selenium, VBA - ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED with chromedriver update 86.0.4240.111

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

It's been working fine until the latest chrome update. As usual I downloaded the latest Chromedriver update to complement the newest release of chrome but now I'm getting the following error once it tries to open a page.

I'm using a proxy so initially I launch chrome without the proxy to ensure there is no connection without proxy, then I launch Putty and connect the proxy server. This has all worked seamlessly until this latest update.

I've included a section of my code below:

```
Public Driver As New WebDriver

Set Driver = New ChromeDriver
Driver.SetProfile Sheets("Settings").Range("B52").Value
Driver.AddArgument ("--proxy-server=socks5://localhost:1194")

'Set download directory
Driver.SetPreference "download.default_directory", Sheets("Settings").Range("B44").Value
Driver.Get "https://www.google.co.uk/", timeout:=none ', False

If Driver.FindElementsByXPath("//*[contains(text(),'The proxy server is refusing connections')]").Count Or Driver.FindElementsByXPath("//*[contains(text(),'There is something wrong with the proxy server')]").Count Then
    Open_Putty_and_Connect_to_Host_Network
end if
```

Error occurs at driver.get

Full Error Message:

```
Run_time error '13':

UnknownError
unknown error: net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED
 (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)
 (Driver info: chromedriver=86.0.4240.22)
(398b0743353ff36fb1b82468f63a3a93b4e2e89e-refs/branch-heads/424
NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)
```

I've been looking online and what I can see I need to pass an argument to the chrome driver but I'm not sure how to or what I need to pass to it.

The code will run beyond this point normally and connect to the proxy and perform it's standard function but I can't understand why this error is occurring or how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!